# How can I determine if an EF5 project is Code-First or Database-First?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I work on project that was created by another programmer the solution contains Entity Framework 5.

I can't figure out which Entity Framework workflow (Code-First or Database-First) it was created with:

Inside my project I have this class:

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//    This code was generated from a template.
//
//    Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.
//    Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace HummerMobile.Core.Data
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;

    public partial class MobileMapEntities : DbContext
    {
        public MobileMapEntities()
            : base("name=MobileMapEntities")
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }

        public DbSet<BaseLayer> BaseLayers { get; set; }
        public DbSet<MapDefinition> MapDefinitions { get; set; }
        public DbSet<MapLayer> MapLayers { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Map> Maps { get; set; }
        public DbSet<SearchConfig> SearchConfigs { get; set; }
        public DbSet<VectorLayer> VectorLayers { get; set; }
        public DbSet<WFSLayer> WFSLayers { get; set; }
        public DbSet<WMSLayer> WMSLayers { get; set; }
        public DbSet<PointFeature> PointFeatures { get; set; }
        public DbSet<PointFeatureAttachment> PointFeatureAttachments { get; set; }
    }
}
```

But also I have some file with `edmx` extension.

Any idea how can I figure out by which Entity Framework attitude it was created?

Comment: What's the difference?  The edmx suggests "database first" but it could also have been "model first", ie a model was designed and both the C# and the tables were generated. What matters is what the entity class definitions look like, post one.

Comment: Looking at your code it seems it is database-first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there's an `*.edmx` file with the same definitions as the `DbContext.tt` / `DbContext.cs` files then it is Database-First (as Code-First never creates `*.edmx` files).

In your case, you said there's an `*.edmx` file - so it's probably Database-First.

Note that it is very possible the project contains two separate EF entity libraries, one using Database-First and the other using Code-First. Ensure that the classes are generated from `.tt` files that are reading from the `*edmx` file to be certain.

However it is not necessarily a choice between just those two - there is also "Code-First from Database" where the entity types are generated as C# directly from the database schema using tooling present in Visual Studio - generally you can spot this from the uniform and less-than-readable style code it generates.

- Database-First:

  1. Visual Studio's tooling inspects a live database schema and generates an `.edmx` file which defines the entities and their relationships.
  2. The `DbContext.tt` T4 template then reads the `edmx` file to generate the entity classes in their own `.cs` files.
  3. This approach can be more maintainable as the EDMX file can be updated incrementally and the entity types automatically regenerated.
- Code-First:

  1. No tooling required. You write everything by hand. No database is required.
  2. This approach is only really suitable for smaller projects, in this author's opinion it's very impractical for large and complicated database designs. It has the advantage of supporting "Database Migrations" automatically but it requires extensive babysitting to handle cases where objects are renamed or when custom ETL logic is needed to transform data from one schema to another.
- Code-First from Database:

  1. Similar to "Database-First" except rather than generating an intermediate EDMX file the tooling generates the entity classes `.cs` files directly.
  2. However the lack of an intermediate EDMX file means that incremental changes at design-time are not supported: the entire set of entity classes and `DbContext` code needs to be regenerated every time the database design changes - which can take a while for complicated databases, which is why Database-First is still very popular in line-of-business applications.